# How to access Database from other computer using sql query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using a SQL database residing on my local computer. I want to access a table from a database residing on another computer using SQL query.

I have been able to connect the remote database with my database and all its tables are shown in Enterprise manager on my local machine. I have added remote SQL Server in my local SQL Server.

When I use select statement in my local SQL server it gives the message database does not exist or access denied.

Any help in this would highly be appreciated.

EDITED

```
Select * from [ServerName].DatabaseName.dbo.tableName
```

Comment: check you connection string

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: from where you are running the Select query?

Comment: Can you post the select query?

Comment: i am running sql query in SQL Server new query window

Comment: I have edited my question with select statement. plz see

Comment: Where did you execute the query? I'm sorry I don't now what _Enterprise manager_ is.

Comment: I am Calling SQL Server Management Studio as Enterprise manager

Comment: You need to create a linked server, but its generally not the best idea. What are you trying to do? http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/how-to-add-a-linked-server

Comment: I am trying to access other databes from other machine in an stored procedure which is giving error

Comment: You need to configure Linked Server, in order to use query like your select statement.

Comment: Configure your linked server and post back any specific issues

Answer (score 2):

Use OPENROWSET
Example

```
    SELECT t.version FROM 
    OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'server=Myserver;UID=xxxx;pwd=yyyy',
    'select @@version version') t
```

Note:

SQLNCLI  is the name of installed OLE DB provider

Datasource: {server=Myserver;UID=xxx;pwd=yyy}

You have  to enable OPENROWSET by executing the following script:

```
  sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
  reconfigure

  go
  sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
   reconfigure
```

OPENROWSET  is like connecting to a  linked server